# How to erase space before very long theorem?

Tags: spacing

I'm now fixing my paper, and I found that there is a large space before a long theorem:

[image]

The theorem is one-page long, so I want to split it so that it fills the big space. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My code seems like the following. I think the problem occurs because of the long contents in align*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
%\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Thorem}
\title{bula bula}
\author{bula bula}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract} 
bula bula
\end{abstract}

\section{introduction}
\lipsum[1-8]

\begin{theorem} %This is the theorem that problem occurs
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

EDIT2: I found a solution, which is simple but not much good. The problem occurred because the theorem contained long equations which was bigger than the space.

```
\begin{theorem}
\begin{align*}
%LONG CONTENTS
\end{align*}
%...
\end{theorem}
```

So I just split the equations as two blocks:

```
\begin{theorem}
\begin{align*}
%CONTENTS 1
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
%CONTENTS 2
\end{align*}
%...
\end{theorem}
```

and it works..

Comment: by default theorem will break among pages... So I suppose you have done something in your code that we have to see (MWE needed: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: @koleygr I added my code, but I don't know whether it'll be helpful or not..

Comment: I updated your example that works for me... 1) Test it after uncommenting `kotex` usepackage command (to see if it causes the problem) 2) Comment the line `\newtheorem{theorem}{Thorem}` and add your own real code's similar line(s) (somewhere you probably have to define the theorem). 3) Add one by one your macros until the problem appear and if can not solve after all that work edit your post with the code that demonstrates the problem. [If you solve it you can answer yourself to help future users]

Comment: @koleygr What is lipsum? It adds some strange sentences a lot.
The problem was because of long equations in align, so I just separated it into two pieces and it works well. What did you intend by using lipsum?

Comment: `lipsum` package used in such cases to provide pseudo-random text. This way My example show that theorem breaks between pages and that your problem was not in the code you had provided but in code we didn't had available for test. Glad that you found the solution. Please edit your post and answer it too (no need to give your real equations if you don't want.... Replace the symbols or whatever with other...)

Comment: You can add `\displaybreak` before the ``\\`` where you'd like an `align*` be broken.